# android - crash when trying to add value to Integer List

Tags: android, list, expandablelistview

In a Layout that contains an `ExpandableListView` I need to maintain the visibility of a `View`. It must be visible when all groups are collapsed. So I did the following:

```
  //class field
  private List<Integer> groupState = null;



 getExpandableListView().setOnGroupExpandListener(
            new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {

                    p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    groupState.add(arg0);

                }

            });
    getExpandableListView().setOnGroupCollapseListener(
            new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    groupState.remove(groupPosition);
                    if (groupState.isEmpty()) {
                        p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            });
```

It crashes with a NullPointerException on the line where I try to add an Integer, no matter which group was clicked. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: where the groupState is  initialized ? its not a question here. !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the complete code, then the proper initialisation of your List groupState is missing.
Somewhere you should have something like this:

```
groupState = new List<Integer();
```

or you change your second line from:

```
private List<Integer> groupState = null;
```

to

```
private List<Integer> groupState = new List<Integer();
```